# center contents of contenteditable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I center the contents of the contenteditable cells.

Below I have a codepen of what I currently have. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvBoYd

My current css is:

```
td, .td {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis ;
  min-width: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  align: center;
}
```

Comment: Turning your `td` into flex containers is a bad idea, as it break a cell's normal behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Use `justify-content: center;` for your cells.

Read more about [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Perfect thanks, didn't realise you could use 'justify-content' on any element.

Comment: @fraserdale Do note, it won't apply the same effect on all display types though.

Comment: @fraserdale you're welcome. If my answer had helped you - you should mark it as final answer.